# Visual Studio 2015 Preview/ASP.NET 5 Core Framework: Type or Namespace Dictionary<,> does not exist

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded the Visual Studio 2015 Preview from Microsoft's website (Version 14.0.22310.1 DP), clicked File -> New Project -> ASP.NET 5 Console Application, generating the default template. Everything builds thus far.

I added the line (`var dictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();`) resulting in the entry method listed below.

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However, on build, the compiler is telling me that the Generic Dictionary implementation is not present in the Core framework. The error message is below:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Dictionary'
>   does not exist in the namespace 'System.Collections.Generic' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)   ProjectName.ASP.NET Core
>   5.0   Program.cs  9

```
project.json file:

{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "commands": { 
        "run" : "run"
    },
    "frameworks" : {
        "aspnet50" : { },
        "aspnetcore50" : { 
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22231"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Under project properties -> application tab. Target KRE Version is the default: KRE-CLR-x86.1.1.0-beta 1.

Unfortunately, the standard Google and StackOverflow search didn't yield the answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add system.collections to your core dependencies, or remove the core framework.

```
    "frameworks" : {
        "aspnet50" : { },
        "aspnetcore50" : { 
            "dependencies": {
               "System.Collections": "",
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22231"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solves the Dictionary issue. However, do you know if there is centralized documentation for the aspnetcore or something that helps with finding the new libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is now in a new assembly, `System.Collections.dll`, and no longer in `mscorlib.dll`? As the error text asks, are you missing an assembly reference from your project file?